# Generating a random connected graph in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I have to do make a generate function for a undirected graph. It has to make a randomly connected graph. First I have to create a spanning tree, then proceed with more edges.

So let's say I have to make a `100-vertice` graph with a density (I guess that is how you say it in English) of let's say `25%`. So I will have to make 1237.5 edges (let's say 1237).

Now I would do this like this:

1. Make a list of all non-used vertices
2. Randomly choose 2 of them, connect them, remove the first one from a list
3. Connect next vertice to the one connected before (the second one, not erased from a list)
4. Do this until we have all vertices used (empty list)
5. Then calculate how many I have to add (1237-100)
6. Now randomly choose 2 vertices, check if they are connected. If not, connect them. Repeat this 1137 times

Now I have a connected graph. The problem is I wrote C++ code for this. It works as intended, but I have to measure the times for some operations (not generation, f.e Prim's algorithm), for densities = `{25, 50, 75, 99}` and for 5 different vertice quantities (f.e from 500 to 5000). I've run a program which would do so. It's running for like a half an hour now. Is there a way so I can optimize my code (by changing steps I did) to make it go faster? (I would especially like step `6` to be more convenient, cuz picking 2 random values and checking if they are not connected (that means, iterating through whole vector of vectors) is not really good, cuz then I can randomly again pick the same values and it can go 4ever)

The code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> undirected_graph::generate(int vertices, int d)
{
    float density = d / 100;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;
    density = density / 100;
    int edges = floor(density * vertices * (vertices - 1) / 2);
    std::vector<int> v_vertices(vertices);
    std::iota(std::begin(v_vertices), std::end(v_vertices), 0);
    std::random_device r;
    std::default_random_engine e1(r()); 
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist2(1, 100);
    int random = 0, random1;
    v_vertices.erase(v_vertices.begin());
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices - 1; i++) // spanning tree
    {   
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist1(0, v_vertices.size() - 1);
        random1 = uniform_dist1(e1);
        data.push_back({ random , v_vertices[random1], uniform_dist2(e1) }); // random edge
        random = v_vertices[random1];
        v_vertices.erase(v_vertices.begin() + random1);     
    }
    // now the additional edges
    int needed = edges - vertices;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist1(0, vertices-1);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist3(0, vertices-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < needed;)
    {
        random = uniform_dist1(e1);
        random1 = uniform_dist3(e1);
        if (random != random1)
        {
            if (!multipleEdgeGenerate(data, random, random1)) // checking if edge like this exists
            {
                data.push_back({ random , v_vertices[random1], uniform_dist2(e1) });
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Need to see code

Comment: Either use memoization or a disjoint data set algorithm such as union-find.

Comment: I actually implemented second one when I was doing Kruskals algorithm. So it would be not O(n) but O(logn), right?